# How do I configure Java Executor to give upper bound thread to each tenant in multi-tenancy application?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multi-tenant

I'm designing a multi-tenancy application that I want to give each tenant an upper bound of the number of thread. But I'm not sure if it's possible to configure that as I don't see any parameters that indicate max thread size in Executor.

This is the example.

```java
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                .setDaemon(true)
                .setNameFormat("ThreadPool")
                .setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
                .build();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, factory);

        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        // TenantA
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            futures.add(runTask(executorService, "TenantA:" + i));
        }

        // TenantB
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            futures.add(runTask(executorService, "TenantB:" + i));
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).whenComplete((v, th) -> {
            System.out.println("Completed");
        }).join();
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<Void> runTask(ExecutorService executorService, String name)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Run task " + name);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Task done");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, executorService);
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is like in the example that `TenantA` and `TenantB` shared the same `Executor` and the total of thread is `10`. The number of tenants can be dynamic like it can grow  if we add more account or reduce if the client leaves.

The question is, is there any configure in Java Executor that can achieve something that if I want to give each tenant max number of thread of 5 so each tenant will get 5. Because what's happening right now is if `TenantA` has 10 tasks or more then `TenantA` will use up all the resources and `TenantB` will have to wait until `A` completed the tasks. One way I want to avoid is to specify in a config per tenant in a config somewhere because the number of tenant can change. So, it would be great if I can just say to Java that you have 1000 threads and each group can use up to 100 so not one account can hog all the resources.

Another solution I can think is to create a `Map<AccountId, ExecutorService>` so each tenant will get their own `ExecutorService` but there might be an obvious solution that I'm missing.

Comment: An alternate solution might be to break the tasks up more granularly, so A and B's tasks both progress incrementally.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in or with an example?

Comment: Using an executor per tenant is the way to go. You could implement a custom executor as well, but that's a lot of work and I doubt if it will give you that much. The greatest disadvantage of multiple executors is that they cannot communicate with each other directly. This will lead to resource problems.

Comment: Also, think in terms of concurrent load that you are expecting, if you expect high concurrent load, load balancing the application is better than playing with threads as too many threads degrade performance